# Solving equation of matrices

Tags: matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices

My problem is maybe extremely simple. I have the following Equation that I have to solve with respect to $B$:

$\sum_{t=2}^T (X_t - B X_{t-1} B^\top) = 0$,

where $X_t$ and $X_{t-1}$ are square and symmetric $n \times n$ matrices, while $B$ is a $n \times n$ square matrix, $B^\top$ its transpose and the $T$ in the summation signs is the number of temporal observations.

I get that I can write it as:

$\sum_{t=2}^T X_t = \sum_{t=2}^T B X_{t-1} B^\top$

but how can I solve it for $B$? I thought that using the trace operator would help but then I would need to invert the trace to a matrix which is more complicated.

Comment: If $\sum X_{t-1}B'$ is invertible, then $$B = \left( \sum X_t \right) \left( \sum X_{t-1}B' \right)^{-1}$$ Otherwise the equation may have no solution.

Comment: In this case, $B$ is still in the right side.

Comment: What is $B'$ then ? I thought it was a misnotation for the matrix $A$ that appears in your question but not in the equation. Please clarify.

Comment: My fault. Now, I have modified the text. There is a single matrix, $B$, that defines a quadratic form over $X_{t-1}$.

Comment: As TheSilverDoe asked, what on earth is $B'$? Also, is $\sum_t(\cdots)$ a finite sum or an infinite sum? If it is an infinite sum, does $\sum_tX_t$ converge?

Comment: $B'$ is the transpose of $B$, I have changed now the notation to be clearer. The sum is not infinite as it goes to $T$, but this is actually not relevant to solve the equation.

Comment: Are matrices $X_t$ positive definite?

Comment: Yes, both $X_t$ and $X_{t-1}$ are positive definite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the equation
$$
\sum_{t=2}^T X_t = B \left(\sum_{t=1}^{T-1} X_t\right) B^\top.
$$
Since $X_t$ are all known, lets replace the sums with some matrices $Y$ and $Z$:
$$
Y = B Z B^\top.
$$
Note that both $Y$ and $Z$ are symmetric and positive definite, so we can represent them using Cholesky decomposition as
$$
Y = LL^\top\\
Z = MM^\top.
$$
The equation becomes
$$
LL^\top = BM M^\top B^\top = BM (BM)^\top.
$$
We may insert $QQ^\top$ where $Q$ is an arbitrary orthogonal matrix between $L$ and $L^\top$:
$$
LQQ^\top L^\top = BM (BM)^\top.
$$
Every $B$ that satisfies
$$
LQ = BM \implies B = LQM^{-1}
$$
would be a solution. Let's prove that there's no other solutions. Multiplying both sides of $LL^\top = BMM^\top B^\top$ with $L^{-1}$ and $L^{-\top}$ gives
$$
I = L^{-1} B M M^\top B^\top L^{-\top} = L^{-1} B M (L^{-1} B M)^\top
$$
and this means that $L^{-1} B M$ is an orthogonal matrix:
$$
Q = L^{-1} B M \implies B = LQM^{-1}.
$$

**Updated** Since the solution is not unique, we have to select one solution based on some assumptions about it. Let's find one that makes $LQ$ as close to $M$ as possible:
$$
\text{minimize } \|LQ - M\|_F^2\\
\text{subject to } Q^T Q = I
$$
This is a variant of [Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem)
$$
Q = \arg \min \|LQ - M\|_F^2 = \\
= \arg \min \|LQ\|_F^2 + \|M\|_F^2 - 2 \langle LQ, M \rangle_F = \\
= \arg \min \|L\|_F^2 + \|M\|_F^2 - 2 \langle LQ, M \rangle_F = \\
= \arg \max \langle LQ, M \rangle_F = \\
= \arg \max \langle Q, L^\top M \rangle_F = \\
= \arg \max \langle Q, U\Sigma V^\top \rangle_F = \\
= \arg \max \langle U^\top Q V, \Sigma \rangle_F
$$
The matrix $U^\top Q V$ is an orthogonal matrix and the maximum is attained when $U^\top Q V = I$, so $Q = UV^\top$ is the solution.
The $U$, $\Sigma$ and $V^\top$ are elements of SVD decomposition of $L^\top M$ product.

Comment: Many thanks! It seems a good solution.

Comment: Which would be a good choice for $Q$?

Comment: That requires some additional knowledge on the field. Probably if $X_{t+1} \approx X_t$ then $B \approx I$ and one may want to choose $Q$ that minimizes $\|B - I\|_F$

Comment: It is indeed that $X_{t+1} \approx X_t$. Solving that minimization, I get $Q = LM^{-1}Y^{-1}Z$, correct?

Comment: That $Q$ does not seem to be orthogonal. I'll expand my answer

Comment: I have $tr[(LQM^{-1}-I)^{\top} (LQM^{-1}-I)] = tr[Q^\top QL^\top L(M^\top M)^{-1} - 2LQM^{-1}+I]$. So $\partial tr/\partial Q = 2QYZ^{-1} - 2LM^{-1} = 0$ which leads me to the solution I posted.

Comment: @A.B. Did you mis the $QQ^\top = I$ constraint in the minimization problem? Your problem has minimum at $Q = L^{-1} M$ where it is zero

Comment: Yes, I guess that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Do you think it would be possible to choose a $Q$ such that the squared spectral radius of $B$ is less than 1?

Comment: @A.B. It depends on $X_t$. If $X_t$ is increasing with time, then probably no. Otherwise, probably yes.

Comment: $X_t$ should be quite stationary through time.